# Symfony php framework creates empty main.css

Tags: php, css, symfony1

I followed [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/04-Project-Setup) tutorial (official documentation for symfony 1.4).

The project is created but the /web/main.css is empty. Is this normal?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the custom file that you should use for your app. It is not the same file used by the "you've successfully created your symfony module". Are you seeing pretty welcome page?

Comment: No it wasn't pretty. But I solved it. I realized that the pretty welcome page is not from project/web/css/main.css but from symfony/web/sf/screen.css. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

just copy the `sf` folder from

```
{sf_project}\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf
```

to

```
{sf_project}\web\
```

Or, you need to define it as an Alias in apache vhost.